# "Unrecognized App" Android Pay API

Tags: android, warnings, android-pay

I'm testing the Android Pay API. I generated the public key by using the command

```
$ openssl ec -in merchant-key.pem -pubout -text -noout
```

and

```
echo $PUBLICKEY | xxd -r -p | base64
```

and put it in the "Android Pay" sample app like this

```
PaymentMethodTokenizationParameters parameters =
                PaymentMethodTokenizationParameters.newBuilder()
                        .setPaymentMethodTokenizationType(PaymentMethodTokenizationType.NETWORK_TOKEN)
                        .addParameter("publicKey", "Key Here")
                        .build();
```

But everytime I try to test the app, i get this warning/error from the WalletFragment
"Unrecognized App. Please make sure you trust this app"

[image]

Comment: Have you figured this out? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Yes. Check out the answer.

Comment: i am also facing same issue , i also don't know, from where i can generate this public key? If you guys have sample example of Google pay , please share it with me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself. All I did was change ENVIRONMENT_TEST to ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX parameter for WalletFragmentOptions.

Answer (score 3):

This error comes when you implement with ENVIRONMENT_TEST . If you will use ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION with signed apk and configure your sha1 key on google account then this message will not come. You are missing pre-authorization in your code.

https://developers.google.com/android-pay/preauth#create_a_client_id